# How to: Add a publish immediately button when editing custom WordPress posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

How to: Add a publish immediately button when editing custom WordPress posts?

I have found to update a custom post type I need to re-edit the scheduled time to save it. Is it possible to simple update the content for custom post types by pressing something like "Current Date" then it will add the current date, there you can publish it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - does clicking 'update' not save the post? You shouldn't need to alter the scheduled time.

Comment: Yeah, for whatever reason it didn't come up with that.. That's what I do now thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above: you should be able to click 'update' in the publish metabox.

If your post is scheduled to be published, it will be updated and still scheduled to be published at that date.

If the post is already published, it is updated (and remains published). If the post is in draft or pending status clicking 'publish' updates and publishes the post.